# finding the amount of child nodes in a database structure

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

hi guys is there a way to count the amount children in firebase?

i have a database structure like this

```
Testitem1{
test: ""
},
Testitem2{
test: ""
}
```

> i want to count only the Testitem nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count child nodes in firebase real-time database.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); // get the reference of child containing testitems
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Log.e(snap.getKey(),snap.getChildrenCount() + "");
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
```